# ¿Cómo eliminar caracteres de una cadena?

Tags: c

Tengo que resolver un problema que al escribir una frase elimine todas las vocales e imprima la frase solo con las consonantes pero que lo imprima junto y en el programa que hice lo unico que hace es que remplaza las vocales con un espacio, ¿Qué podria hacer para que lo imprima todo junto?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {

    char cadena[50];
    int i, j, s;
    printf("inserta tu frase plox: ");
    gets(cadena);
    s=strlen(cadena);
    j=' ';
    for(i=0;i<s;i++){
        if(cadena[i]=='a'||cadena[i]=='e'||cadena[i]=='i'||cadena[i]=='o'||cadena[i]=='u'){
            cadena[i]=j;
        }
    }
    printf("%s\n\n", cadena);
    printf("ya elimine todas las vocales, ahora dame mi titulo >:v");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ¿Por qué no vas directamente imprimiendo las consonantes a medida que recorres el array? No hay una forma de "eliminar" un elemento del array y que todo se corra de lugar automáticamente (y hacerlo obviamente sería un esfuerzo sin sentido). ¿Por qué `j` es `int`? Te funciona porque C hace el cast implícito, pero conceptualmente está mal.

Comment: tienes razon ya lo cambie a tipo char, y gracias por la idea ya modifique el codigo muchas gracias

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como puse en el comentario, puedes directamente imprimir las consonantes en lugar de preocuparte por modificar el array. Básicamente debes hacer esto:

```
for (i = 0; i < s; i++) {
     if (cadena[i] != 'a' && cadena[i] != 'e' && cadena[i] != 'i' && cadena[i] != 'o' && cadena[i] != 'u') {
         putchar(cadena[i]);
     }
}
```

Con esto no necesitas de `j`. Aprovecho para recomendarte que le pongas nombres significativos a las variables, porque luego te topas con `a`, `t`, `x`, etc. y no recuerdas qué es cada cosa. En vez de `s` pon algo del estilo `longCadena` (si prefieres usar nombres en español).

Por otro lado con `gets` puedes tener problemas si el usuario ingresa más de 49 caracteres. Para evitar esto puedes usar `fgets` (no voy a ahondar en esto, si buscas encontrás bastante información al respecto).

Comment: intente hacerlo como lo hiciste en ese ejemplo pero me aparece un error que hay pocos datos para usar putc

Comment: Es verdad, porque `putc` requiere que le indiques dónde poner el caracter, que en este caso es `stdout` (`putc(cadena[i], stdout)`). Puedes usar directamente `putchar`.

Comment: muchas gracias tendré que investigar sobre esas funciones, me ayudo bastante

Answer (score 4):

Básicamente lo que tienes que hacer es crear otra cadena y pasar los caracteres a la nueva cadena (excepto los que tú le indiques). Y para finalizar a la nueva cadena le agregas el '\0' para indicar el fin de la misma.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {

char cadena[50];
char tmpCad[80];
int i, s, j = 0;

printf("Ingrese la cadena: ");

gets(cadena);
s = strlen(cadena);

for (i = 0; i < s; i++)
{
    if (cadena[i] != 'a' && cadena[i] != 'e')
    {
        tmpCad[j] = cadena[i];
        j++;
    }
}

tmpCad[j] = '\0';

printf("%s\n", tmpCad);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: `tmpCad` jamás será más grande que `cadena`, ¿para qué hacerla de 80? Creo que cabe aclarar por si hay algún distraído que falta comparar contra las demás vocales.

Comment: Costumbre declarar como 80, tranquilamente le puede poner el valor que necesite...

Answer (score 3):

Retomando el ejemplo de JBeccaceci, podrías meterlo en una función con malloc tipo char*:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX 100

char *eliminar_vocales(char *cadena) {
    char *cadena_temporal = malloc(strlen(cadena)+1);
    int j = 0;
        for (int i=0; i<strlen(cadena); i++) {
            switch (cadena[i]) {
                case 'a': break;
                case 'e': break;
                case 'i': break;
                case 'o': break;
                case 'u': break;
                default:
                cadena_temporal[j] = cadena[i];
                j++;
            }
        }
    cadena_temporal[j] = '\0';
    return cadena_temporal;
}

int main() {
    char leer[MAX];
    printf("Escribe la cadena para eliminar las vocales:\n");
    scanf("%s", &leer);
    char *cadena_final = eliminar_vocales(leer);
    printf("Esta es la cadena sin vocales: %s\n", cadena_final);
    free(cadena_final);
    return 0;
}
```