# ¿Cómo puedo recorrer una cadena y eliminar una palabra de la misma?

Tags: c

```c
printf("Escribe los nombres de tus animales favoritos.\n");

do {
    printf("Nombre de un animal: ");
    fgets(name, sizeof(name),stdin);

    strcpy(animales[cuantos], name);
    cuantos++;

    printf("Quieres escribir otro animal (s/n) ");
    salir = getchar();
    getchar();

}while (salir == 's' && cuantos < MAX_NAMES);
```

Lo anterior es el código que realicé para guardar la palabra en la cadena pero no logro eliminar algo dentro de ella, aunque sé cómo recorrerla.

Comment: [Algo así](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/577145/169744) te sirve?

Comment: Define "eliminar" ¿Cambia el tamaño de la cadena original? ¿Cambias los caracteres de la palabra por otros caracteres? Por ejemplo puedo eliminar `dolor` en: `Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet` reemplazando cada caracter con una letra `x` asi: `Lorem ipsum xxxxx sit amet`. La palabra `dolor` ha sido eliminada.

Comment: Exacto, tal como lo describes Mauricio, solo que al eliminar no se reemplazara por una letra o simbolo.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Cómo eliminar caracteres de una cadena?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/53205/c%c3%b3mo-eliminar-caracteres-de-una-cadena)

Comment: Tu pregunta no parece coincidir con el código que publicas. En la pregunta hablas de eliminar una palabra de una _cadena_ (que yo entiendo como _string_). Pero en tu código estás añadiendo palabras a una _array_.

Answer (score 0):

Con la funcion strnstr puedes buscar una cadena mas pequeña dentro de otra cadena mas grande pasandole un total de n caracteres, eso te devuelve un puntero al inicion de la cadena y lo puedes usar para a partir de ahi sustituir n caracteres de la cadena principal. Yo tiraria por ahi en principio.

DESCRIPCIÓN
La función "strnstr()" localiza la primera aparición de la cadena "little", que es una cadena terminada en nulo, en la cadena "big". La búsqueda se limita a no más de "len" caracteres. Los caracteres que aparecen después de un carácter '\0' no se buscan.

VALORES DE RETORNO
Si "little" es una cadena vacía, se devuelve "big"; si "little" no se encuentra en "big", se devuelve NULL; de lo contrario, se devuelve un puntero al primer carácter de la primera aparición de "little".

Por ejemplo, si tenemos la cadena "big" con el valor "Hola mundo" y la cadena "little" con el valor "mun", al llamar a la función "strnstr()" con estos argumentos y un valor de "len" igual a 8, la función buscará la cadena "mun" dentro de los primeros 8 caracteres de la cadena "big" ("Hola mun") y devolverá un puntero al primer carácter de la primera aparición de "little", en este caso "m".

```
    char    *ft_strnstr(const char *big, const char *little, size_t len)
    {
        size_t  i;
        size_t  j;

        i = 0;
        if (*little == 0)
            return ((char *)big);
        while (*big && i < len)
        {
            j = 0;
            while (*(big + j) == *(little + j) && *(big + j) && (i + j) < len)
                j++;
            if (*(little + j) == '\0')
                return ((char *)big);
            big++;
            i++;
        }
    return (NULL);
    }
```

Comment: No funcionamos como foro. Preguntas y respuestas. Puedes crear UNA respuesta y añadir todo lo relevante a esa respuesta. Te ayudo moviendo el código a la respuesta. Puedes borrar la otra "respuesta"